# Cannot import header file

Tags: objective-c

I have a class. Its header file looks like this

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

typedef void (^SpinnerViewCompletionBlock)();

@interface ABResultsControllerSpinnerView : UIView

- (void)startAnimation;
- (void)stopAnimation;

- (void)startAnimationWithCompletion: (SpinnerViewCompletionBlock)completion;
- (void)stopAnimationWithCompletion: (SpinnerViewCompletionBlock)completion;

- (UIColor *)spinnerColor;

@end
```

Inside .m file I have this

```
#import "Masonry.h"
```

The problem is that compiler gives me an error of that it cannot find `"Masonry.h"`. But the file is in the project.

What is the issue ?

Comment: Make sure the file is not only added to the project but it is located in the project folder.

Comment: That was the point. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the file is located in the project folder.

The compiler doesn't use all the headers added to project, it uses all the headers that can be found in *header search path*. By default this path is set to be the project folder. Therefore, if your header is outside the search path, the compiler cannot see it.

It's important to understand that the C compiler doesn't work only files added to the the Xcode project but sometimes with the file structure instead (e.g. for headers). Some very difficult to find bugs can be caused by this - e.g. when there are two header files with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had the `C` files within my project but they were in a folder `CUtilities`.

So I had to change

`#import "utility.h"`

to

`#import "CUtilities/utility.h"`